# Elapsed International Power

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, wordplay, physics, symbols

[image: Elapsed International Power]

Clues: [contextual images] [beefcake horse] [beefcake horse reversed with 261] [x10]

Instructions: Name That Movie

_ _ _ _ T _ _ _ _ _ _ T _ _ _

Comment: Prob has something to do with rot13(gur havg "ubefr cbjre": 1 CF = 0,74569987 Xvybjngg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the movie we're looking for is

> **BACK TO THE FUTURE**

The beefcake horses must represent

> Horsepower

The number '261' written on the second horse may indicate

> That we should write the number '162' on the first horse, as it faces in the reverse direction.
>  Overall this would give '162261' which we multiply by 10 to get **1622610**

The title indicates

> That we should convert to the SI unit of power (*International Power*) which is the Watt. Converting 1622610 horsepower to watts gives 1209980277 Watts or, roughly **1.21 Gigawatts**

Where have I heard that before?

> If you have seen the movie, you might remember Doc Brown telling Marty that that's the amount of power needed to work the DeLorean time machine and we see that the movie title fits the clue.

Other part of title

> The word "elapsed" is synonymous with "past" and a big part of the movie involves travelling into the past.